# Could the Qilin exist?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures

[image]

The [Qilin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qilin) or [Kirin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qilin) is commonly depicted as:

- having a reddish orange mane
- resembling a horse
- having a branch like horn
- have goat hooves
- are herbivores
- being a dark seafoam green coloration
- having a somewhat long tail ending with a horse tail
- are covered in something which resembles fish scales
- have have what appears to be a beard and eyebrows
- will actively try and avoid harming any creatures
- are solitary
- are semi-aquatic

Given these characteristics, what species could the Qilin have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to such a being?

Comment: Behemoth or Qilin? You mention both. Or are they the same?

Comment: @Harel13 Qilin i just forgot to remove all mentions of the Behemoth which copying and pasting

Comment: I.M.H.O.   Using Copy/Paste to "ask" a question is both disingenous and diminishes both the OP and The reader.  For an example of a *Truly Great* question, please see: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/146090/how-soon-can-the-first-stars-form

Comment: @Joe OK i just thought that this and my Behemoth question were similar enough to where i could Copy/Paste the basic outline without taking away from the question but i understand what you mean

Comment: I appreciate that this is a unique, mythical creature. It's a lot more interesting and arguably more on-topic to ask about folklore rather than video game characters when designing a fictional world. That being said, does this question provide new / useful / interesting insights? You've described a multicolor horse with a horn. Plenty of animals on Earth are multicolor, a few have horns, and at least one is even a literal horse. Anatomically Correct questions aren't really helpful imo unless they provide more specific, challenging, and inexplicable attributes.

Comment: Sexual dimorphism? Some of these could be secondary sexual characteristics that one gender has and the other doesn't?

Comment: @Zxyrra most likely **not** a horse of any kind. A horse is an [odd-toed ungulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-toed_ungulate) and the requirement of cloven hooves makes the creature an [even-toed ungulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-toed_ungulate).

Comment: @Spencer I think that's a minor detail that doesn't negate the fact that this creature is already plausible and easy to explain.

Comment: VTC: poor quality, as it's a copy-paste of other questions. Make this about your world or make it of use & interest to others!